# is there a template language for json rendering?

Tags: asp.net, json, template-engine

as xslt is for xml is there a template language for json rendering(server side), supported by C#, asp .net?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use mustache.

- http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html - docs
- https://github.com/jdiamond/Nustache - link to project